# Screw Terminals versus crimp terminals in a mating connector

Tags: connector

I have a project where I have to make 300 six wire connectors. I'm highly considering using screw terminals on one end of the connector, but I don't know if they provide enough stress relief on the copper to last long.

Would I be better served by using legitimate crimped terminals in a mating connector that goes to a compatible header?

I just don't want to crimp 3600 wires, but obviously I want a quality wire in the end.

This harness is going to be a fixed application in a vehicle, so while there's not much strain on the wire, there will be vibrations to contend with. It will interface a vehicle connector with a small PCB I've designed.

I'm looking at [this screw terminal](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-282837-2.html)

[image]and [this connector family](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/brands/ampmodu/ampmodu-modiv.html).
[image]

Comment: Why not use Wago-style spring terminals instead of screws?

Comment: What is the AWG of these wires? If they are small, I would use IDC connectors so I don't have to strip 1800 wires or or turn 1800 screws.

Comment: Screw terminals and other terminals work fine. But as far as I know they are for applications where the wire harness is not under constant motion. I don't think they provide strain relief in that sense. Maybe you could include a bit more detail about what you are doing (in the original question, not in the comment section).

Comment: @peufeu - I wasn't familiar with Wago Style spring terminals. They look like they could work.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Wire is going to be 22 AWG.

Comment: @mkeith - I've updated the post to include the application of the harness :)

Comment: IDC connectors are very fast to attach, and you don't need to crimp every individual pin.

Comment: at 22awg, yeah idc

Comment: Can anyone recommend a good product like for 22 AWG IDC Connectors / Headers? I'm having trouble finding a full wire to board solution.

Comment: there idc blocks too where you insert the end of the wire

Comment: I found one after quickly checking JST website. The JST XAF series of connectors. Please be advised that technically shopping questions are considered off-topic. Right now your question is not a shopping question. But I suppose it could turn into one. Good luck!